# Demorgans Law negation on sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let's say I have the sets $D, S, \text{and}, G$ meaning that a certain group is unrepresented. The intersection of the three set $D \cap S \cap G$ means that **all** of the groups are unrepresented. After applying DeMorgan's Law to the intersection of the three sets it becomes $D' \cup S' \cup G'$. What is the meaning of this set? Does this mean **none** of the groups will be represented or **at least** one of the groups will be represented?

If you guys need the homework problem I am working on for context, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that "**none** of the groups will be **unrepresented**". Or, equivalently, "**at least one** of the groups will be **represented**".